# I am new to Latex, can someone help me here?

Tags: cls

```
Runaway argument?
\x@protect \[\protect \[  \@nil  \@ifpackageloaded {amstex}{\def \@tempa \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.1581 \newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
                   

phd.cls
1581
Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.1581 \newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par

phd.cls

LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `phd', but the document class provides `amsthm'.
```

Comment: it would be helpful to upload code which can be run in a latex editor

Comment: The warning means you wrote `\documentclass{phd}` and there is a class file `phd.cls` in your path, but in that file it says `\ProvidesClass{amsthm}` instead of `\ProvidesClass{phd}`. Is this a custom class?